How to add font features in tailwind.config?
This is my current tailwind.conf.js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['InterVariable', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

I would like to add font features for sans:
{
  fontFeatureSettings: '"cv11", "ss01"',
  fontVariationSettings: '"opsz" 32'
}

I've tried adding like this but it didn't work:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['InterVariable', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans, 
          {
            fontFeatureSettings: '"cv11", "ss01"',
            fontVariationSettings: '"opsz" 32'
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}

How can I add font features globally?

If you want to create a custom utility for these font features update your tailwind.config.js like this :
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['InterVariable', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    function({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.font-feature-sans': {
          fontFeatureSettings: '"cv11", "ss01"',
          fontVariationSettings: '"opsz" 32',
        },
      });
    },
  ],
};

Use the custom utility class in your HTML:
<p class="font-feature-sans font-sans">
  This text has font features and variations applied globally.
</p>


I was looking for something more global, where I don't even have to introduce new utility class, as described here - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family. But unfortunately I can't combine it with my current configuration.
